# How to upload a video to YouTube using YouTube API and MediaStreamSource

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm building a relay service that will pass videos from an external server to YouTube. Currently my code is working as intended but I need to avoid to save the file locally ahead of time to do the upload to YouTube using MediaFileSource. Is there a way to pass an InputStream instead of a file and use MediaStreamSource instead to allow piping?

https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/media/MediaStreamSource

That way I'm able to pipe the files directly like so

```
 YouTubeService youTubeService = new YouTubeService("My-Service", developerKey);
 youTubeService.setUserCredentials(user, password);

 VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

 YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
 mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
 mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("Song Title");
 mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Category"));
 mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
 mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("Test");
 mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
 mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent("Song Description");
 mg.setPrivate(false);

 MediaStreamSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/video.mp4").openStream(), "video/mp4");
 newEntry.setMediaStream(ms);

 String uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
 VideoEntry createdEntry = youTubeService.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
 return createdEntry.getHtmlLink().getHref();
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an error and had to edit my code as:

```
String title = "Test Video";
youTubeService.getRequestFactory().setHeader("Slug", title);
```

Thought I should mention because I didn't see this in your snippet. But the upload is taking an insanely long time. Any progress at your end with the upload?

Comment: No support for MediaStreamSource

Comment: I ended up not using the YouTube API